# Nightmare js Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I can't make nightmare js work:

My code

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
  nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true
  });

console.log('fer');

nightmare
  .goto('http://www.google.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('name[btnK]')
  .wait('#main')
  .evaluate(function() {
    console.log('xxxxxx');
    var x = document.querySelector('.srg .g');
    var item = x.querySelector("h3").textContent;
    console.log(item);
  })
  .end() // end the Nightmare instance along with the Electron instance it wraps
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Error

```
set DEBUG=nightmare & node src\crawler\google-spider.js
  nightmare queuing process start +0ms
fer
  nightmare queueing action "goto" for http://www.google.com +10ms
  nightmare queueing action "type" +23ms
  nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
  nightmare queueing action "wait" +1ms
  nightmare queueing action "evaluate" +0ms
  nightmare running +1ms
  nightmare electron child process exited with code 0: success! +5s
(node:7912) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Cannot read property 'focus' of null
```

Is there a way to show where it fails, or what is the property null

nightmare electron child process exited with code 0: success! +5s
    (node:7912) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all nightmare messages:

DEBUG=nightmare*

Answer (score 0):

The `type` call generates the error, I know because only `type` call focus property.

Also `console.log('xxxxxx');` will not be shown because code inside evaluate runs on the Electron instance.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in case webpage is not loaded fully. Try to add ".wait(1000)" after ".goto".